# Using CDN vs Installing library by NPM

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, npm

I recently started using NPM, but I don't understand how the files in `node_modules` are added to my `index.html`.

**Case 1: CDN**

For example, if I want to use jQuery via CDN, it is so simple! I add the CDN link to a `<script>` tag on my `index.html` file and `$` is immediately available.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').css('background','red');
});
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Case 2: NPM**

Now I'm trying to use node modules and npm rather than CDNs. I have done the following:

1. Created `package.json` by using `npm init --yes`
2. Installed the jQuery package with `npm install jquery --save`

Now, my project folder looks like this:
[image: Directory in windows showing a node modules folder, index.html file, and package.json file.]

I have removed the script tag with the link to the jQuery CDN from `index.html`, but I don't understand how to add jQuery from `node_modules`?

I am doing this on a browser.

Comment: use the import statement

Comment: This file lies in a directory, so you need to make it available over HTTP protocol so that once `index.html` is loaded - browser can fetch it. How would you do it depends on what server stack are you using. Is it Express?

Comment: @madalinivascu I think OP wants to use jQuery on the browser-side, just host it on his/her own rather than use CDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your question... But can't you just add this line to your `index.html` file?

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: which one is best practice ?

Comment: This doesn't work. NPM packages have to be exported as modules.

Comment: The one I listed is a quick and dirty way to get the project going; however, usually I would do that on a real project. Either I use CDN for the benefit mentioned by @jamil, or jQuery is already bundled with the library/framework I'm using anyway.

Comment: It does work, and I've done it many times. Again, I don't recommend it on a real application but it does work.

Answer (score 53):

**CDN**

Use CDN if you are developing a website that will be accessible by public internet users.

CDN Benefits:

- Will be cached on most browsers because it's used by a lot of other websites
- Reduce the bandwidth

check for more benefits [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/7-reasons-to-use-a-cdn/)

**NPM**

npm is a great tool to manage dependencies in your app using a [module bundler](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-modules-bundling-transpiling/).

Example:

assume using a [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) module bundler and `jQuery` is installed

```
import $ from 'jQuery'
...
var content = $('#id').html();
```

but the browser does not understand the `import` statement so you have to transpile the code with Webpack commands, the bundler will check all the used dependencies and bind them in a single file without any dependencies problems.

Useful links: [Getting started with webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/)

Comment: link for the webpack "first steps": https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/

Comment: Parcel, Grunt, and Gulp are also alternatives to Webpack.

Comment: @applemonkey496 but keep in mind that module bundlers like Parcel and Webpack are different from Grunt and Gulp which are task runners and they will not look for the dependency graph.

Comment: @OmarHegazi yes, you do have a point there. I take back my comment about Grunt and Gulp, but Parcel is still a good alternative to webpack, especially if you don't like or need complicated configuration

Comment: "Use CDN if you are developing a website that will be accessible by internet users." -- isn't this virtually 100% of websites by definition? I'm not sure this answer helps me decide when to use a CDN vs a bundler, but it seems to evaluate to "never use a bundler" based on this.

Comment: which improves the browser performance and which lowers ( React web app)

Comment: @ggorlen there are use-cases where you don't have internet access. E.g. offline devices that are operated through a web-based GUI - and with stuff like Electron, you can build desktop applications that are web-based, but should function even if offline.

Comment: @Jeppe Naturally there are offline use cases, but the point of my comment is to highlight the discrepancy between the sweeping statement "Use CDN if you are developing a website that will be accessible by internet users" and the reality that most "websites that will be accessible by internet users" primarily use bundlers like Webpack. Clearly, whether a site is on the internet or not isn't the critical factor in choosing between CDN or a bundler. Also, websites that have offline features can still use CDNs and cache the lib, assuming they're online for initial page load.

Comment: @ggorlen Okay I see your point. But I don't think the question is CDN vs webpack - you could bundle with webpack and host that on a CDN. Webpack structures dependencies very well compared to bloating your HTML with CDN script references. With ES6/typescript imports, it is also easier with an explicit import from `node_modules` (webpack has the `externals` property for that I believe). You also get more control about what is bundled, with CDNs you get the full asset. But I agree this answer is not very nuanced.

Comment: @Jeppe Yep, those are much clearer reasons to me. The question is npm vs CDN so technically you could bloat your code without bundling by direct linking to your npm modules (worst of both worlds) or bundle and self-host on CDN but I assume OP means the normal uses of these two approaches, bundling your npm modules versus a shared CDN.

Answer (score 6):

in addition to above, `npm install` packages to local also:

1. let your local IDE provide code intellisense and type-checking;
2. provide source code for (Webpack) bundling, which combines all the JavaScript files to be a (minified) single file, so no dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to host jQuery yourself and use it within a web app running in the browser.

If so, you need to host this file - make it downloadable via the same web server you are using to host `index.html`.

If you are using Express, you might do something like this on the server side:

```
app.use('jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));
```

And then reference the file in `index.html`:

```
<script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
```

See [Express' manual for serving static files](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

If you're not using Express, you need to consult your web server's stack manual. No way to guess unfortunately - I gave an Express.js example because this is probably the single most popular package like that for node.js.

Answer (score 1):

Just to try to add some clarity to this.

A CDN hosts code on a third party server network that your front end code accesses when the page loads. You don’t need to worry about hosting the code with your web site.

NPM is intended for use in a development environment that combines the whole NPM sourced code base on your dev or production web site.

The difference being that the CDN is responsible for serving the third party code to your web page. With NPM you are responsible for serving the same code and the related performance and maintenance of that code.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be "filed" unless you link the js file in your template (replacing the CDN one). A bundler output or your compiled and public js file needs to be linked instead of the CDN link URI.